# Writing an Element to a file

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am using `ElementTree` to create, parse and modify XML files and object. I am creating the tree like this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
foo = etree.Element("root")
etree.SubElement(foo, "extra", { "id": "50" })
```

then, I want to write this to a file. According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write), I should use an `ElementTree` object for that, but how to create that from the `Element`?

I tried

```
e = etree.ElementTree(foo)
e.write(filename)
```

but that doesn't work:

> TypeError: must be str, not bytes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your opened file should be opened with `b` (binary) flag:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

foo = etree.Element("root")
etree.SubElement(foo, "extra", { "id": "50" })
e = etree.ElementTree(foo)
with open('test.xml', 'wb') as f:
    e.write(f)
```

or just pass a filename/path to `write()`:

```
e.write('test.xml')
```

Comment: @BartFriederichs yeah, or just a filename string.